# In IntelliJ 11.1 on os x using emacs mode M-B inputs unicode integral

Tags: macos, emacs, unicode, intellij-idea

Using the default emacs keybinding for IntelliJ 11.1 on os x I attempt go back a word using M-B (or literally option-B) instead of moving back a word the unicode integral symbol is entered. M-B (option-B) works fine in my emacs install.

Comment: No answer yet? Shame :(

Comment: What does `C-h k M-B` tell you is the command associated with that key? What happens when you start from `emacs -Q` (no init file) --- can you reproduce the problem? There's not a lot of info in your quetion.  It's not even clear what your last sentence means; e.g., what is your install?

Answer (score 3):

Download this keyboard layout: https://github.com/idf/dotfiles/blob/master/keylayout/OptDisabled.keylayout

To enable your new layout you must save it into your '~/Library/Keyboard Layouts', and then enable it from System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources.

Then, with this keyboard layout, you can use meta keys in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like JDK 8u60 solves this issue. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-17392#comment=27-983397

Comment: Yes. I installed the [JDK 8u60](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html), restarted IntelliJ and it is working fine now.

Comment: I use jdk 8u66, intellij 14.1.4, Alt+b still not work after I restart intellij. Is there anything I should do?

Comment: Check which JDK IntelliJ is actually using in About IntelliJ. Also, you could try updating to 15, that comes with a bundled JDK?